# Is it bad etiquette to contact a named reviewer?

Tags: publications, etiquette, peer-review

A named reviewer has made some suggestions, which I'm exploring, and I'd like to ask for input on a particular point. I have exchanged emails with this person before asking for input on the same work. Would it be appropriate to email directly to ask?

Comment: You need to get it out of your head that research should be done in private and then revealed to the world as a perfect, singular entity, rather than what we all know it to really be - a collaborative and uncertain wander through the unknown. The whole point of peer review is to improve the quality of the research, not as a barrier to publishing at all, so embrace your peers :)

Comment: The question is about the etiquette of directly contacting a reviewer, not keeping research private.

Answer (score 4):

If the reviewer has given you their name, then that is their choice. In my experience journals give the reviewers the option of anonymity. If they've chosen to reveal their name then I think there is no issue with you contacting them directly. Especially if you've discussed the work with them previously.

When you resubmit the paper, with the changes, perhaps you could then include this persons name in the list of people not suitable for reviewing the paper (Assuming that this journal asks you to submit names of suitable, and not suitable, reviewers).

Answer (score 3):

Better to do this through your editor, to avoid any appearance of impropriety.

Answer (score 1):

I usually give my name when doing peer reviews, but I would not want to be directly contacted.  Individual reviewers have no control over the editor's decisions or opinions, and you might be misled into following a reviewer's opinion that the editor feels is incorrect or minor.  It also might give the impression of trying to influence a reviewer directly, which would be improper.

Work through the editor.